# SliverPersistentHeader without using CustomScrollView

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver, nestedscrollview

I had a `CustomScrollView` which looked like:

```dart
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    SliverPersistentHeader(
      floating: true,
      delegate: MyPersistentHeaderDelegate(),
    ),
    SliverList(...),
  ],
)
```

Because I had to change the layout to use masonry layout I am using `flutter_staggered_grid_view` packages `MasonryGridView`. The problem is it does not support slivers and therefor i cannot use it in CustomScrollView.

The question is how can I now still use my SliverPersistentHeader (/Delegate) without using a CustomScrollView?

Ive tried using a `NestedScrollView` but all the examples only show how it works with CustomScrollView:

```dart
NestedScrollView(
  floatHeaderSlivers: true,
  headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext _, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
    return <Widget>[
        SliverOverlapAbsorber(
            handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
            sliver: SliverPersistentHeader(
                delegate: MyPersistentHeaderDelegate(),
                floating: true,
            ),
        ),
    ];
  },
  body: CustomScrollView(
    sliver: [
        SliverOverlapInjector(handle: handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context)),

        // wont work in sliver because it uses its own scroll view
        MasonryGridView.builder(),
    ]
  )
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can use the `SliverMasonryGrid` widget inside a `CustomScrollView`, as explained in [flutter_staggered_grid_view's wiki](https://github.com/letsar/flutter_staggered_grid_view/wiki/Masonry).

Here's a code sample inspired by the documentation that has been working well for me:

### Code sample

```dart
class SliverMasonryPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SliverMasonryPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverPersistentHeader(
            floating: true,
            delegate: MyPersistentHeaderDelegate(),
          ),
          SliverMasonryGrid.count(
            childCount: 100,
            crossAxisCount: 4,
            itemBuilder: (_, i) => Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
              ),
              child: Text('$i'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```